# Почему не работает UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

Мой ViewController, внутри которого есть UICollectionView. Использую исключительно в качестве таблицы, в которую загоняются данные из JSON. Внутри 16 клеток, с идентификаторами cell1-cell16

```
class FirstViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        table.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"cell")
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
    {
        var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

При запуске получаю ошибку

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "9pv-A4-QxB-view-tsR-hK-woN" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.
```

При простом перетаскивании UICollectionView не отображаются клетки.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: ваш контроллер унаследован от UICollectionViewController, а при загрузке что то там не сходится у xcode. предложу вам проверить и в коде и в interface builder, что и контроллер и его `.view` являются соответствующими классами

Comment: Может быть, есть какой-нибудь туториал по добавлению UICollectionView с нуля? Или, может быть, есть другие способы создания таблиц?

Comment: закиньте свой код куда нить. посмотрю что у вас там происходит

Comment: https://zuberok@bitbucket.org/zuberok/aqe-ios.git изначальная задача: отображать клетки в FirstViewController. В коде нужно только менять значения 8 из 16 клеток, так что, я думаю, можно сделать все без использования UICollectionViewController

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander это хороший вопрос, на англоязычном SO ответ на него имеет под сотню upvotes. Он полезен начинающим разработчикам. Если вы не хотите на него отвечать, зачем лезть с комментариями?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko он никому не полезен, потому что это мусорный вопрос. Посмотрите на код, наследуемся от `UICollectionViewController` и при этом храним в проперти `UICollectionView!`, которое названо `table`. Может лучше почитать книжку ? Т.к. администрация это никак не присекает, таких вопросов становится все больше и больше, желания заходить на SO у меня все меньше и меньше

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander если вы знаете, как это решить так напишите ответ. может и вам 100 upvotes будет. :)

Comment: Тут не на что отвечать. Вы будете отвечать на вопрос "Ребята, а как в свифте объявляются пременные ?" Это очевидно любому, кто хоть начинал читать учебник по ios. Тут то же самое, как реализовать UICollectionViewController/UITableVIewControlller - вообще Xcode сам генерит нужный проект, когда указывается Master-Detail VC.

Comment: @amazingbasil код с нитхаба не компилируется вообще - пишет нет библиотеки Charts. а firstViewController почему то совсем не такой, как у вас в вопросе

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander задавайте вопрос на мете. если сообщество согласно, что таким вопросам тут не место, будем минусовать нещадно и удалять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что за отображение ячеек отвечает класс `UICollectionViewCell`, тебе надо его создать и присвоить ячейке во вкладке `Identity inspector`. После этого должно все заработать.

К сожалению на русском языке туториал я не подскажу, но на английском есть очень годный https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1